# Can't format new 3TB disk with NTFS (but it works on linux)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I recently purchased a Seagate Barracuda 3TB drive (ST3000DM001) and I'm trying to get it to work on Windows 8. I've an old motherboard Asus P5K Premium.

The system recognizes as 2.7GB, I create a new partition with 1000GB but when go to the formatting it fails.

I've tried with MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition for Windows and also tried GParted in Linux but the NTFS formatting fails every time.

But the strange situation here is when I do a clean linux installation on the disk, I got the 2.7GB available and the system working normally.

What can be the problem?

ps: Also tried to install the Asus Unlocker application but for an unknown reason the installation fails on my system.

EDIT:

When I try to format with Computer Management, after a few minutes it shows "The format did not complete successfully".

When I try to mark partition as active it shows "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error"

Comment: Which error do you get when it fails to format in windows?

Comment: Shows the error "The format did not complete successfully".

Comment: Try creating an empty (no-filesystem) partition in Linux and then use the Linux `mkntfs` command on it, as in `mkntfs /dev/sdb5` (changing `/dev/sdb5` as necessary, and typing this as `root` or preceding it by `sudo`, depending on your distribution). If that fails, report the error message that Linux generates and type `dmesg | tail` and post the output from that command.

Comment: For testing purposes only try creating a 10gb partition does that fail?

Comment: What about quick format?

Comment: It seems the Asus P5K Premium is old enough that it only has BIOS. **Windows requires UEFI to be booted from a GPT disk**. So if you don't have another MBR disk you can't install Windows (at least without some hassle)

Answer (score 0):

To work with disks which are 2TB or more you must convert it to GPT. NTFS is only a partition format, not related to harddisk format

Comment: The disk is already in the GPT format. But thank you for the input.